# Upgrade from MaaS 2.6.2 to MaaS 2.7

Tags: upgrade, maas

There seems like a lot of fixes and also network tests in 2.7 that I would like to take advantage of.  I see the Snap install for 2.7 but I'm trying to understand the upgrade path.  I don't want to destroy the existing db in MaaS 2.6.2 with all of the machines.

Do you do a `snap install...` and `maas init` and just don't reinitialize the db?

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maas/2.7`, making the new MAAS packages available by apt. Followed by apt update and upgrade. It just works fine. 
For new installations you can use snap, but upgrading existing installations using apt should be fine as far as I know. It's always a good idea to take a [backup](https://maas.io/docs/backup) of the database first.